# Javascript time saved incorrectly in sql server table

Tags: sql-server, html, datetime

```
new Date(moment().year(), moment().month(), moment().day(), vm.newHearing().HearingTime().split(":")[0], vm.newHearing().HearingTime().split(":")[1]).toLocaleString()
```

The client side value for a date column is 11/5/2013 10:15:00 AM. The time is selected from HTML5 time input control.

When I check in database after saving the entity, it shows me incorrect time value:
11/5/2013 3:15:00 PM

Comment: Time zone difference perhaps?  Datetime values should be persisted in UTC anyway, maybe that's what it's (correctly) doing?  (That is... Is the client at GMT -5?)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which is fine except you aren't using it *properly*

Try this instead:

```
moment(vm.newHearing().HearingTime(), "HH:mm").toISOString()
```

That will pass the selected time, on the current day, from the user's *local* time zone, converted to UTC time and in ISO format.

Now that might not be exactly what you want to do.  Depending on your requirements, you might instead want this:

```
moment.utc(vm.newHearing().HearingTime(), "HH:mm").toISOString()
```

Which is almost the same thing except that it assumes the input time is *already* in UTC.

Or you might want this:

```
moment(vm.newHearing().HearingTime(), "HH:mm").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
```

This one doesn't try to convert to UTC at all.

For all choices, I emit the date string in ISO8601 format.  Since you are sending it back to the server, this is the best choice.  When you used `toLocaleString`, that generates a format that is appropriat for *display* only.